# Despite creating file association, file will not open in my Application

Tags: java, eclipse, registry, file-association

In my registry, for the extension '.conf' I made the (Default) value point to the pathway of my App. However when I try clicking a file with the extension '.conf' the window asking the user to select a program still opens, rather than simply opening the app associated with the extension. Am I declaring something wrong?

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.conf]
@="C:\\Users\\izhodzis\\workspace\\ConfCompiler\\src\\ConfCompiler.jar"
```

PS. The idea is that it will work on other peoples' computers. They shouldn't need to select "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"

[image: So I am ok with having this pop up open because...]
[image: Now I have this when I try to use the Java program]

Comment: How does the OS know what to do with a .jar file?  Did you set that up too?

Comment: @JimGarrison Well if I go into Documents and simply open the .jar file it works fine. I am just unable to make the OS (Operating System <=?) automatically open the .jar when a .conf file is selected.

Comment: When you double-click a .jar there's a registry entry that invokes `java -jar whatever.jar`.  However,   I don't believe document associations are transitive -- i.e. you're asking for the OS to go `.conf -> .jar ->java.exe `, which I doubt will work. You will probably have to set your registry entry to do the same thing (invoke java.exe) with your jar file and the target file as an argument on the command line.

Comment: @JimGarrison Do you have an idea of why it tries to open the .conf file AS a .jar file? I am very confused right now. This is my first time ever doing registry manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regedit should look something like this: `PATH_TO_JAVAW -jar PATH_TO_CONFCOMPILER`

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\j2rex.y.z\\bin\\javaw.exe -jar C:\\Users\\izhodzis\\workspace\\ConfCompiler\\src\\ConfCompiler.jar"
```

That probably won't work but hopefully it would help you further.